# Anonymous Objects in Java

Tags: java

Java helps us creating anonymous object using

```
new class_name();
```

statement and calling the methods using association(.) operator like

```
new Emp().input();
```

How can I use it to invoke two methods simultaneously from an anonymous object like invoking both `input()` and `show()` together ?

Comment: you cannot. because the object is not referenced, it is basically lost once the method returns. Some apis use the fluent interface pattern, but it is still quite rare.

Comment: you need to call `Emp e = new Emp(); e.input(); e.show();`. Why is that not an acceptable solution, btw?

Comment: @njzk2 Not really ``anonymous`` if you assign it to a name ;)

Comment: @aruisdante: exactly. My comment should be rephrased : `why do you need the object to be anonymous?`

Comment: Just as a general piece of advice, I would caution against trying to make your code __too__ terse. The fluent pattern is fine, but on the other hand, so is writing this as three lines. There have been lines that did a zillion things at once that I've looked at and thought, "it'd be more readable if we split these up" -- but it's _very_ rare that I look at 3 or 4 lines and think, "this would be more readable if we smushed these into one line."

Comment: Well, why would you want this, in the first place? What do you call an *anonymous* object? Classes may be anonymous, but there is no such (standard) term for instances. Whether you assign the object to a local variable or not, it has no practical effect on its behavior. So feel free to use the @njzk2 's solution -- it makes no difference to the resulting byte code.

Comment: And by the way, afaik, the dot (".") is not an operator in Java and it is not called an "association".

Answer (score 13):

or

```
public Emp show() {
    // do the stuff
    return this;
}
public Emp input() {
    // do the stuff
    return this;
}
```

Then call with

```
new Emp().show().input();
```

Comment: That would be the *fluent interface pattern* mentioned by @njzk2

Comment: don't forget to replace void with the return type :-)

Comment: The `voids` should be `Emp`. :)

Comment: Thanks paul and Roddy for the fix

Answer (score 4):

How about making a method:

```
public void inputThenShow() {
    input();
    show();
}
```

Then call with

```
new Emp().inputThenShow();
```

Comment: Method `ShowAndInput()` should be `showAndInput()` camel cased with lower first letter to follow Java coding style + conventions. Also, personally, I'd want the method to be called `inputThenShow()` or similar to indicate the order of the implemented actions.

Comment: This should really be an exception and not the norm. Generally it is very bad to have the word `and` in your method names.

Comment: Why is it bad? And there is no `and` in the method name.

Comment: @Zach The original version did. But I think what skiwi is referencing is the idea of a method having a [single responsibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle), which is a common, a generally considered "good", practice in OO. Its not so much the word "and" itself, its the principle violation which it implies (at least I think that's what skiwi meant).

Answer (score 1):

What you can also do, without modifying the `Emp` class, is create an anonymous class that extends your class to allow it to call both methods.

```
new Emp() {
    public void doStuff() {
        input();
        show();
    }
}.doStuff();
```

Which as a bonus gives you an anonymous instance of an anonymous class.

Comment: Except when it (here: `Emp`) is a final class