# BlueJ Auction exercise 4.47

Tags: java, bluej

The `makeABid` method includes the following two statements:

```
Bid bid = new Bid(bidder, value);
boolean successful = selectedLot.bidFor(bid);
```

The bid variable is only used here as a placeholder for the newly created Bid object before it is passed immediately to the lot’s `bidFor` method. Rewrite these statements to eliminate the bid variable by using an anonymous object as seen in the `enterLot` method.

Any help?

Comment: What is `enterLot` method referred to in your task?

Comment: `boolean successful = selectedLot.bidFor(new Bid(bidder, value));` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Anonymous Objects in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24916639/anonymous-objects-in-java)